# Apache Archiva using JDK 11 throwing BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roleManager'

Tags: java, spring, jetty, archiva, java-11

Using apache archiva with Oracle JDK 11 configured on Windows with class path. The exception trace shows as following on running `archiva.bat console` using PowerShell

```
PS D:\Programs\apache-archiva-2.2.3\bin> .\archiva.bat console
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | 2018-10-31 11:29:42.367:WARN:oejd.ContextDeployer:ContextDeployer is deprecated. Use ContextProvider
jvm 1    | 2018-10-31 11:29:42.382:WARN:oejd.WebAppDeployer:WebAppDeployer is deprecated. Use WebAppProvider
jvm 1    | 2018-10-31 11:29:42.538:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.14.v20131031
jvm 1    | 2018-10-31 11:29:42.554:INFO:oejs.NCSARequestLog:Opened D:\Programs\apache-archiva-2.2.3\logs\request-20181031.log
jvm 1    | 2018-10-31 11:29:42.601:INFO:oejd.ContextDeployer:Deploy D:\Programs\apache-archiva-2.2.3\contexts\archiva.xml -> o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,null},D:\Programs\apache-archiva-2.2.3/apps/archiva
jvm 1    | 2018-10-31 11:29:45.956:INFO:oejpw.PlusConfiguration:No Transaction manager found - if your webapp requires one, please configure one.
jvm 1    | 2018-10-31 11:29:45.997:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
jvm 1    | 2018-10-31 11:29:47.133:INFO:/:Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
jvm 1    | Oct 31, 2018 11:29:58 AM org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool init
jvm 1    | WARNING: maxIdle is larger than maxActive, setting maxIdle to: 20
jvm 1    | 2018-10-31 11:30:00.543:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,file:/D:/Programs/apache-archiva-2.2.3/apps/archiva/},D:\Programs\apache-archiva-2.2.3/apps/archiva
jvm 1    | org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'repositorySearch#maven' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/Programs/apache-archiva-2.2.3/apps/archiva/WEB-INF/lib/archiva-indexer-2.2.3.jar!/org/apache/archiva/indexer/search/MavenRepositorySearch.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type [org.apache.archiva.admin.model.managed.ManagedRepositoryAdmin]: : Error creating bean with name 'managedRepositoryAdmin#default': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected org.apache.archiva.redback.role.RoleManager org.apache.archiva.admin.repository.managed.DefaultManagedRepositoryAdmin.roleManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roleManager': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'managedRepositoryAdmin#default': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected org.apache.archiva.redback.role.RoleManager org.apache.archiva.admin.repository.managed.DefaultManagedRepositoryAdmin.roleManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roleManager': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
.
.
.

jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:96)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
jvm 1    |      at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
jvm 1    | Caused by:
jvm 1    | org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'managedRepositoryAdmin#default': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected org.apache.archiva.redback.role.RoleManager org.apache.archiva.admin.repository.managed.DefaultManagedRepositoryAdmin.roleManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roleManager': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
.
.
.

jvm 1    |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
jvm 1    |      at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
jvm 1    | Caused by:
jvm 1    | org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected org.apache.archiva.redback.role.RoleManager org.apache.archiva.admin.repository.managed.DefaultManagedRepositoryAdmin.roleManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roleManager': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:571)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
.
.
.
jvm 1    |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
jvm 1    |      at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
jvm 1    | Caused by:
jvm 1    | org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roleManager': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1145)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1069)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:543)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1145)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1069)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
.
.
.
jvm 1    |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
jvm 1    |      at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
jvm 1    | Caused by:
jvm 1    | java.lang.NullPointerException
jvm 1    |      at java.base/java.util.Arrays.binarySearch(Arrays.java:2382)
jvm 1    |      at org.jpox.TypeManager.isDefaultEmbeddedType(TypeManager.java:559)
jvm 1    |      at org.jpox.metadata.AbstractPropertyMetaData.populate(AbstractPropertyMetaData.java:744)
jvm 1    |      at org.jpox.metadata.ClassMetaData.populatePropertyMetaData(ClassMetaData.java:434)
jvm 1    |      at org.jpox.metadata.ClassMetaData.populate(ClassMetaData.java:246)
jvm 1    |      at org.jpox.metadata.MetaDataManager.populateFileMetaData(MetaDataManager.java:1060)
jvm 1    |      at org.jpox.metadata.JDOMetaDataManager.loadMetaDataForClass(JDOMetaDataManager.java:608)
jvm 1    |      at org.jpox.metadata.JDOMetaDataManager.getMetaDataForClassInternal(JDOMetaDataManager.java:313)
jvm 1    |      at org.jpox.metadata.MetaDataManager.getMetaDataForClass(MetaDataManager.java:377)
jvm 1    |      at org.jpox.AbstractPersistenceManager.hasMetaDataForPersistenceCapableClass(AbstractPersistenceManager.java:4113)
jvm 1    |      at org.jpox.AbstractPersistenceManager.assertPersistenceCapableClass(AbstractPersistenceManager.java:4143)
jvm 1    |      at org.jpox.AbstractPersistenceManager.newObjectIdInstance(AbstractPersistenceManager.java:2382)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.archiva.redback.rbac.jdo.JdoTool.getObjectById(JdoTool.java:313)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.archiva.redback.rbac.jdo.JdoRbacManager.getResource(JdoRbacManager.java:479)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.archiva.redback.rbac.jdo.JdoRbacManager.createResource(JdoRbacManager.java:439)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.archiva.web.security.ArchivaRbacManager.createResource(ArchivaRbacManager.java:564)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.archiva.redback.role.processor.DefaultRoleModelProcessor.processResources(DefaultRoleModelProcessor.java:94)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.archiva.redback.role.processor.DefaultRoleModelProcessor.process(DefaultRoleModelProcessor.java:75)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.archiva.redback.role.DefaultRoleManager.loadApplication(DefaultRoleManager.java:183)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.archiva.redback.role.DefaultRoleManager.loadRoleModel(DefaultRoleManager.java:119)
jvm 1    |      at org.apache.archiva.redback.role.DefaultRoleManager.initialize(DefaultRoleManager.java:509)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:354)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:305)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1145)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1069)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:543)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1145)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1069)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
jvm 1    |      at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:782)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:424)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:774)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:249)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer.deploy(ContextDeployer.java:359)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer.access$000(ContextDeployer.java:82)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer$ScannerListener.fileAdded(ContextDeployer.java:107)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:615)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:540)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:403)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:336)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.ContextDeployer.doStart(ContextDeployer.java:421)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:81)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:96)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1274)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1197)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:473)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:615)
jvm 1    |      at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:96)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
jvm 1    |      at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240)
jvm 1    |      at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Only modification of configuration I did is adding some jars listed below and adding them in `wrapper.conf` as below

```
wrapper.java.classpath.27=%REPO_DIR%/jaxws-api-2.3.1.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.28=%REPO_DIR%/jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.29=%REPO_DIR%/jaxb-core-2.3.0.1.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.30=%REPO_DIR%/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.31=%REPO_DIR%/javax.transaction-api-1.3.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.32=%REPO_DIR%/tomcat-juli-9.0.12.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.33=%REPO_DIR%/javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar
```

Comment: Which Spring version? Anything below Spring 5.1 officially doesn't support Java11.

Comment: As I see from the source on github it is 4.3.10.RELEASE. No way to run with some compatibility options and dependencies ?. Seems I will get a version for just Archiva. Any free open source alternative to use as maven repository ?

Comment: Spring 4.3 works on Java 8, anything above it will probably fail (also due to other libraries like cglib and asm not supporting anything higher in that version). Unless there is another version of Archiva that is specially for Java11 you should stick with Java8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just in case someone facing this issue. It seems Spring 4 which is used by Archiva 2.2.3 (2017) does not support being running on Java 11 VM and I can't get it to. Thanks to @M. Deinum in comments providing the info

> Spring 4.3 works on Java 8, anything above it will probably fail (also
>   due to other libraries like cglib and asm not supporting anything
>   higher in that version). Unless there is another version of Archiva
>   that is specially for Java11 you should stick with Java8

In short, stick with Java8 for Archiva as runtime. Also same in documentation about Nexus.

Comment: Where can we change the java being used by Archiva ?

Comment: according to the [documentation](https://archiva.apache.org/docs/2.2.8/adminguide/standalone.html), it's in `wrapper.conf`